# Java reduce number of constructors

Tags: java, builder-pattern

Suppose I have some class that has constructors, each of which has 2 params
for example I have 5 types, two of them can be passed as first param and three as second

Suppose the types are A,B,C,D,E. Basically I have something like this:

```
public SomeClass(A,C) {}
public SomeClass(A,D) {}
public SomeClass(A,E) {}

public SomeClass(B,C) {}
public SomeClass(B,D) {}
public SomeClass(B,E) {}
```

So as you can see there are all possible combinations of these types
and there aren't optional params, like in standard builder pattern.

What can I do to reduce number of constructors? Is there some pattern to help me?

EDIT

I can't use standard builder because if I supplied A then I can't supply B 
and if I supplied C then I can't supply D or E

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34726422/passing-properties-to-factory-method/34752184#34752184

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is with using the builder pattern?

Comment: @Nayuki they are all of them but some time there can be more and I just want to find the answer to my question

Comment: you can but it involves lots of if and else in a single constructor which make a messy code.

Comment: @Pooya yeah constructor youre describing is awful

Comment: What do you do with the parameters? I mean, if the 5 types are different, do you have 5 fields, only 2 of which are not null? If so, you should consider subclassing.

Comment: @Andreas I have only 2 fields and the types are different, so I cant upcast them to one class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a restricted builder pattern:

```
class MyBuilder {

    public MyBuilder(A) { ... }
    public MyBuilder(B) { ... }

    public SomeClass build(C) { ... }
    public SomeClass build(D) { ... }
    public SomeClass build(E) { ... }

}
```

Example usage:

```
new MyBuilder(A).build(C)
```

If you have only 6 possible combinations, I would probably tolerate the complexity and duplication in the existing code. But if there are more possibilities and/or the code will be extended in the future, then I would recommend this pattern here.

---

You can extend this pattern to more arguments, but it gets uglier because you need more intermediate classes. For 3 arguments, you might implement something like:

```
class MyBuilder1 {
    public MyBuilder1(A) { ... }
    public MyBuilder1(B) { ... }

    public MyBuilder2 build(C) { ... }
    public MyBuilder2 build(D) { ... }
    public MyBuilder2 build(E) { ... }

    class MyBuilder2 {
        public MyBuilder2(C) { ... }
        public MyBuilder2(D) { ... }
        public MyBuilder2(E) { ... }

        public SomeClass build(F) { ... }
        public SomeClass build(G) { ... }
    }
}

SomeClass x = new MyBuilder1(B).build(D).build(F);
```

Unfortunately the intermediate stage needs duplication of methods and constructors for types C, D, E.

Comment: hmm it can be acceptable in my case, but what if there are 3 params and so on?

Comment: If you have 3 params, you might want to use the standard builder pattern. Unless you want to strictly enforce the order of params.

Comment: I've added EDIT, look at it please

Comment: @MikeHerasimov My answer already respects the additional rule you mentioned. Do you see how C/D/E returns SomeClass instead of MyBuilder?

Comment: yeah youre right, but only if there are 2 params in constructor (+1 btw)

Comment: For 3 params: You can always make MyBuilder1 to create MyBuilder2 which then creates SomeClass

Comment: uhum you mean Builder1 holds first and second param and Builder2 holds  all and call needed constructor

Comment: and Builder1 returns instance of Builder2

Answer (score 0):

Create 2 interfaces, one for your first parameter, one for your second parameter. A and B implement the first one, C,D and E the second one.

Comment: huh, but what if some of types aren't my custom types, for example one of them is String

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion.  Put the logic into your builder equivalent class.  Add a method to check that the parameter combination is valid.

```
class MyBuilder {

  int paramA;
  bool paramAset = false;

  long paramB
  bool paramBset = false;

  // etc for all parameters.

  void setParamA(int newAval) {
    if (checkParamA(newAval)) {
      paramA = newVal;
      paramAset = true;
    }
  }

  void setParamB(long newBval) {
    if (checkParamB(newBval)) {
      paramB = newBval;
      paramBset = true;
    }
  }

  // etc. for all parameters.

  // Parameter checker method.
  bool checkValid() {
    if (
        paramAset && !paramBset && /* other params */ ||
        !paramAset && paramBset && /* other params */ ||
        // other allowed parameter combinations
       ) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

} // end class MyBuilder
```

Each parameter has its own value and a boolean to indicate whether it is set.  The checker method only allows valid combinations of the booleans.  Note that each parameter is specified as either set or not set in the checker to catch all invalid combinations.  Your constructor for the main class needs to call the checker method and fail appropriately if the combination is invalid.